# Prove that $(f, g, h)$ is a linearly independent list of vectors in $\mathbb{R}[x]^S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

"Recall that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a vector space. Suppose that $f, g, h \in \mathbb{R}[x]^S$ and that there is $q \in S$ such that $f(q) = 1$, $g(q) = x^2 + 1$, and $h(q) = x^2 + x$. Prove that $(f, g, h)$ is a linearly independent list of vectors in $\mathbb{R}[x]^S$"

My attempt:

Suppose that $a_1f + a_2g + a_3h = 0$ $\forall s \in S$

Then $a_1f + a_2g + a_3h = 0$ for $s=q$

Hence $a_1(1) + a_2(x^2+1) + a_3(x^2+x) = 0$

Suppose x = 0. Then $a_1(1) + a_2(1) + a_3(0) = 0 \iff a_1 = -a_2$

Suppose x = -1. Then $a_1(1) + a_2(2) + a_3(0) = 0 \iff a_1 = -2a_2$

Thus $a_1 = -a_2 = -2a_2 \iff a_2 = 2a_2 \iff a_2 = 0 \iff a_1 = 0$

Now suppose x = 1. Then $0(1) + 0(2) + a_3(2) = 0 \iff a_3(2) = 0 \iff a_3 = 0$

Because the only solution to the equation is $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$ it follows that (f,g,h) is a linearly independent list of vectors in $\mathbb{R}[x]^S$

I have no idea if I'm on the right track or not...

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}[x]^{S}$ meant to denote the space of $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps between the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $S$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]$? That is, does $\mathbb{R}[x]^{S} = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(S, \mathbb{R}[x])$?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this part of a previous question "Let V be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}. $ Let $S$ be a non-empty set and $V^S$ the set of functions from $S$ to $V$. "